# Map JSON string array to List<String> using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I have following JSON returned from server.

```
 String json = {
    "values": ["name","city","dob","zip"]
 };
```

I want to use `ObjectMapper` to return the `List<String>` values. Something like:

```
List<String> response = mapper.readValue(json, List.class)
```

I have tried several ways but none of them worked. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit:** I don't want additional wrapper objects. I want to straight away get the `List<String>` out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could define a wrapper class as following:

```java
public class Wrapper {

    private List<String> values;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Then use:

```java
Wrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
List<String> values = wrapper.getValues();
```

---

If you want to avoid a wrapper class, try the following:

```java
JsonNode valuesNode = mapper.readTree(json).get("values");

List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (JsonNode node : valuesNode) {
    values.add(node.asText());
}
```

Comment: Correct, I can do that and in fact, I have that solution already in place. But, I didn't want to have that Wrapper. Is it possible, Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ Cássio Mazzochi Molin - Thank you

Comment: the second one worked in my case. I initially tried using wrapper class. But jackson was throwing issues with constructor not finding and similar ones, which didn't go away when I tried to resolve them. the second option worked flawlessly though.

Answer (score 47):

The TypeFactory in Jackson allows to map directly to collections and other complex types:

```
String json = "[ \"abc\", \"def\" ]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<String> list = mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class));
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward way, without using unnecessary wrappers or resorting to the low-level tree API. Of course, it also works with complex classes, not just strings.

Comment: This isn't what OP wants. Won't work with JSON array field, only with top-level ones.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way you might be interested in, partly similar to accepted answer but can be written as one-liner (line breaks should help with understanding).

Input JSON:

```
{
    "values": ["name", "city", "dob", "zip"]
}
```

Code snippet:

```
String json = "{\"values\":[\"name\",\"city\",\"dob\",\"zip\"]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
    mapper.convertValue(
        mapper.readTree(json).get("values"),
        String[].class
    )
);

list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This code snippet outputs the following:

```
name
city
dob
zip
```

Please note that `Arrays.asList()` returns a list of fixed size because it is backed by a given array. To get a resizable list just wrap it like that:

```
List<String> resizableList = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"})
);
```

---

Of course this solution can be adapted to more complex cases, not just `String`s.

For example, for a given POJO `User`:

```
class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "[User = {id: %d, name: \"%s\"}]",
            id,
            name
        );
    }
}
```

and input JSON:

```
{
    "values": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Alice"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ]
}
```

following code snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"values\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Alice\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Bob\"}]}";

List<User> list = Arrays.asList(
    mapper.convertValue(
        mapper.readTree(json).get("values"),
        User[].class
    )
);

list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

yelds the following output:

```
[User = {id: 1, name: "Alice"}]
[User = {id: 2, name: "Bob"}]
```